# Search Post data php custom input variables

Tags: php, mysql, variables, search

I'm trying to figure out a way to have custom input variables for a $_POST search form.

so let's say the user inputs

"user:" - into the search field, it will search for a user.
"battle:" - it searches for a battle
"sample:" it searches for a sample. Etc.

How do I go about using the $_POST method? I was thinking about

```
$user_search_check = (!empty($_POST['searchbox'])){
     if (beginning of line first five letters are 'user:'){
       $user_search = "true";
       }
}
```

then to use it I would say

```
if ($user_search == "true"){
 // RUN SELECT SCRIPT FOR MYSQL
}
```

But i'm not sure on how to get the first five letter. Or should I just take off everything BUT the first five letters and check if it says user?

As always, any help much appreciated and thanks in advance :)

Comment: i would have a drop down with the list of 'key words' (user,battle ..) you can search for, then the a box for the text searched for. saves have to instruct the user what the words are or accommodate them misspelling them etc

Comment: i actually want it this way though, i'm trying to give the site the feel of old consoles

Comment: ok so when they misspell or miss out the colon you just want it to fail ? explode() on the colon, use the array results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$firstFive = substr($_POST['searchbox'],0,5);
```

Comment: limited, not all words will be four letters long

Comment: i concur. really just needs to check the first letter potentially.

Comment: explode on colon, seems to be the best option, still think this approach is ill-conceived

Comment: youre absolutely right. a dropdown list or separate search buttons would be nicer

Comment: i guess substr works perfectly for this particular case. Actually, explode does as well. My brain must be exploding.